# Why do some photos show entirely black when exporting a 1080p slideshow from iPhoto?

Tags: software, troubleshooting, iphoto, slideshow

I used to make slideshows with iPhoto and export as video.
Today I'm trying to make another one but some photos appear totally black when exporting in 1080p...

I tried to export at lower resolutions, and everything works ok.

So it's only when exporting at 1080p...

Comment: Is there anything you can identify as common about the photos that don't show?

Comment: @mattdm Nothing really. And it's not always the same photos that are shown black between two exports.

Comment: I'm actually trying with the photos resized to lower

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the images were all too big.
I suppose iPhoto can't handle this amount of very high res photos, all around 5616*3744px in my case.

I resized all the images to a little higher than 1080p, and it worked well.